# Unable to Kill Whatever Process is Running on Port 80

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, localhost, port

[***EDIT: I tried searching again with command lsof -wni tcp:80 and another process comes up with the name google but on a different port and I noticed that whenever I kill that process it just kills Google. Happened with the command mentioned below but I just didn't notice the first time]

I have completely killed all my terminal windows and closed out, but there is still something running on localhost:80. I am on a mac and in my terminal I searched:

```
lsof -i tcp:80
```

And something came up with info under COMMAND that says Google and PID was 270.

I typed:

```
kill -9 270.
```

Did another search. Nothing there. But still when I go to localhost:80, in the browser it says "It works!" which was something I used to write in the past whenever I just wanted to check and see if something was functioning before proceeding.

I have no idea how to get rid of this. Tried several other suggestions based on internet searches and none work.

Is there a command I can run that will kill every process on every port so that I don't have to go through this again? Please help! (Time sensitive matter). Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

This helped me out and I was able to fix. Turns out I had my apache server running in the background from a project like 2 years ago lol.

Discovered issue from this link: https://www.mkyong.com/mac/mac-osx-what-program-is-using-port-80/ and then ran:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure why I could not find the process with `ps -e`, perhaps I did not know what i was looking for. Either way, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `sudo` to kill process binded to a port lower than 1024.

You may also have a service running that spawn new processes

[More information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only#16568)

Comment: Tried using sudo
httpd   3053 root    4u  IPv6 0xc2a8211b33005af      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN) and that does not work either. Here's what happens when I enter that: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   3059 _www    4u  IPv6 0xc2a8211b33005af      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN).

Comment: Then when I search again I get this: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   3067 root    4u  IPv6 0xc2a8211b330006f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   3073 _www    4u  IPv6 0xc2a8211b330006f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: Same processes but with different PID numbers.

Comment: Then you have another process that create new ones

Comment: Ok so how do I find and kill that process that is creating new processes?

Comment: Get the ppid (parent process id) of the process you try to kill. Check https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line#150131

Comment: Thanks but I'm on OSX not Linux.